# Expressing an ellipse with polar coordinates

Tags: polar-coordinates

We have the following ellipse:

$2(x+1)^2+(y+1)^2 \le 16$

So the polar coordinates will be:

$x = -1 + A\cos(\phi)$

$y = -1 + r\sin(\phi)$

Where $0 \le r \le 4$ and $0 \le \phi \le 2\pi$.

This is pretty easy, however I have trouble determining the coefficient for $x$, $A$ since we get $\frac{2(x+1)^2}{4}$. How do we determine the coefficient so that it is true when $0 \le r \le 4$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since$$2(x+1)^2+(y+1)^2\leqslant16\iff\frac{(x+1)^2}8+\frac{(y+1)^2}{16}\leqslant1,$$the expression of the ellipse in polar coordinates is $x=2\sqrt2r\cos\phi$ and $y=4r\sin\phi$, with $0\leqslant r\leqslant1$ and $0\leqslant\phi\leqslant2\pi$.

Comment: Thank you and then if I want it on the form $0 \le r \le 4$ I just divide by $4$ and get $x=r/\sqrt2cos\phi$

Comment: @osk Yes, that's it. I should have expressed my answer with $0\leqslant r\leqslant 4$, since tha't what you wanted.